# Splitting string and keeping delimiter ends up splitting delimiter as well

Tags: r, regex, string, split, delimiter

I've been looking around for answers to this but I just keep doing something wrong with regex, and other solutions haven't been able to fix this.

I am trying to split the following string, splitting by any word that ends with "ministeren" and until a ")" sign - for this string:

> "og holder sig alene til den. \r\n Finansministeren (Scharling): For"

I want to get the following:

[1] "og holder sig alene til den. \r\n"
[2] "Finansministeren (Scharling): For"

But this is what I get:

[1] "holder sig alene til den. \r\n "
[2] "F"
[3] "i"
[4] "n"
[5] "a"
[6] "n"
[7] "s"
[8] "m"
[9] "inisteren (Scharling): For

I use the following code in R:

```
strsplit(tekst_test, "(?<=.[a-zA-Z]*ministeren \\([a-zA-Z]*)", perl=T)
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: PCRE regex does not support lookbehinds with variable length patterns.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Does that mean there is no regex solution to this?

Comment: I doubt regex is the right way for several K PDF pages.

Answer (score 1):

With base R:

```
x <- "og holder sig alene til den. \r\n Finansministeren (Scharling): For"


a <- sub(" Finansministeren.*", "", x)  
b <- sub(".*\r\n ", "", x)

c(a,b)

[1] "og holder sig alene til den. \r\n"
[2] "Finansministeren (Scharling): For"
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not sure this quite solves it. See, I have a lot of text (of which I only gave an example). The structure is "x(x(x Finansministeren (Scharling): x(x(x Statsministeren (Hansen): x(x(x Forsvarsministeren (Madsen): x(x(x"

This structure goes on for 1000 pdf pages or more.

As you see, I need to split just before every occurrence of a word containing "ministeren" until the next "(".

What I would want in the above instance:

[1] "Finansministeren (Scharling): x(x(x"
[2] "Statsministeren (Hansen): x(x(x"
[3] "Forsvarsministeren (Madsen): x(x(x"

Answer (score 0):

If you actually just need to get the matching part, then you can use `stringr::str_match_all` (`regmatches` from base R and `stringr::str_match` only return the first match):

```
> tekst_test="og holder sig alene til den. \r\n Finansministeren (Scharling): For annanministeren (Svensson)"
> str_match_all(tekst_test,"[a-zA-Z]*ministeren \\([a-zA-Z]*\\)")[[1]][,1]
[1] "Finansministeren (Scharling)" "annanministeren (Svensson)"
> str_match(tekst_test,"[a-zA-Z]*ministeren \\([a-zA-Z]*\\)")
     [,1]
[1,] "Finansministeren (Scharling)"
> regmatches(tekst_test,regexpr("[a-zA-Z]*ministeren \\([a-zA-Z]*\\)",tekst_test))
[1] "Finansministeren (Scharling)"
```

Comment: Thanks! But I actually need to not lose any text but split with the mentioned pattern. 

I have a lot of text (of which I only gave an example). 

The structure is "x(x(x Finansministeren (Scharling): x(x(x Statsministeren (Hansen): x(x(x Forsvarsministeren (Madsen): x(x(x" This structure goes on for 1000 pdf pages. As you see, I need to split just before every occurrence of a word containing "ministeren" until the next "(". 

What I would want in the above instance: 
[1] "Finansministeren (Scharling): x(x(x" [2] "Statsministeren (Hansen): x(x(x" [3] "Forsvarsministeren (Madsen): x(x(x"

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
strsplit(string, "(?<=.)(?=\\b\\w*ministeren\\w*\\b \\()", perl=T)
```